# Tron Bike Game Java (Moving character through JPanels)

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel

I'm designing a Tron Bike game using Java, with two characters who let out a trail behind them as they are constantly moving.

Arena consists of a 2-d Array of JPanels in a JPanel in a JFrame. I found it easiest with that structure.

I can't figure out how to actually move a character through multiple JPanels and have them turn with a KeyListener. Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Here is the code for my Arena class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Arena extends JPanel
{

public Arena()
{

    setLayout(new GridLayout(15,15,0,0));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel[][] grids = new JPanel[15][15];

    for(int r = 0;r<grids.length;r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0;c<grids[0].length;c++)
        {
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25,25));
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            add(panel);
        }
    }
}
public static void play()
{
    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    fr.setTitle("Arena");
    fr.setSize(520,540);
    fr.setLocation(400,130);
    fr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fr.setResizable(false);
    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container contentPane = fr.getContentPane();
    Color col = new Color(0,213,255);
    contentPane.setBackground(col);

    Arena ar = new Arena();

    fr.add(ar);

    fr.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use just one large `JPanel` if the transition between the panels cause your problems?

Comment: Just a side note.  `Arena` is `JPanel`, you don't need `battle`, it simply doesn't make sense...

Comment: You could use `JLabel` instead and change it's icons?

Comment: @DanielLerps I only want horizontal and vertical movements, nothing in between. I'd assume the only way to do that is with a grid.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I fixed that up. Also, I would have the same problems with moving characters through JLabels.

Comment: If you use `Point2D` from `java.awt.geom` to store the bike positions you can permit vertical movements by checking that only one coordinate (x or y) changes for one move.

Comment: @DanielLerps I don't understand how this can be used with JPanels

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a single JPanel to represent the arena area, with a backing BufferedImage to store the trail data?  You'd override JPanel.paintComponent() to pass the BufferedImage to Graphics.drawImage() to draw the updated scene each frame.  This would give you a lot more resolution, and you would only have to listen for keystrokes on a single object.  Collisions could be implemented by using BufferedImage.getRGB(x, y) to determine whether any trail data had been already written into the position that the cycle is entering.